# SystemOutOfmemory in IIS

Tags: asp.net, windows, iis

The server is Windows 2012R2 with IIS.

I have a website with about 100 applications (Folder Convert to application).

It was worked fine for 3 years and before the last windows updates.

After those updates even i have unistalled them, i have a strange problem with the error SystemOutOfMemory, in some apps, not the same every time, and it happens randomly through the day.
This is the error from the Event Viewer

```
      Event code: 3008 
      Event message: A configuration error has occurred. 
      Event time: 14/12/2022 1:08:36 μμ 
      Event time (UTC): 14/12/2022 11:08:36 πμ 
      Event ID: 2860d96182e74faa8a4a62e0e943e591 
      Event sequence: 147 
      Event occurrence: 1 
      Event detail code: 0 

      Application information: 
      Application domain: /LM/W3SVC/10/ROOT/www.mysite.gr-161-133154865200911346 
      Trust level: Full 
      Application Virtual Path: /www.prana.gr 
      Application Path: C:\inetpub\vhost\mydomain\httpdocs\www.mysite.gr\ 
      Machine name: VMI1110479 

       Process information: 
       Process ID: 3456 
       Process name: w3wp.exe 
       Account name: VMI1110479\IWPD_2(mycloud) 

       Exception information: 
       Exception type: ConfigurationErrorsException 
       Exception message: Exception of type 'System.OutOfMemoryException' was thrown.
       at System.Web.Configuration.CompilationSection.LoadAssemblyHelper(String 
       assemblyName, Boolean starDirective)
       at    
       System.Web.Configuration.CompilationSection.
 LoadAllAssembliesFromAppDomainBinDirectory()
at System.Web.Configuration.CompilationSection.LoadAssembly(AssemblyInfo ai)
 at System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.GetReferencedAssemblies(CompilationSection 
compConfig)
at System.Web.Compilation.WebDirectoryBatchCompiler..ctor(VirtualDirectory vdir)
at 
System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.BatchCompileWebDirectoryInternal(VirtualDirectory 
vdir, Boolean ignoreErrors)
at System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.BatchCompileWebDirectory(VirtualDirectory vdir, 
VirtualPath virtualDir, Boolean ignoreErrors)
at System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.CompileWebFile(VirtualPath virtualPath)
at System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.GetVPathBuildResultInternal(VirtualPath virtualPath, Boolean noBuild, Boolean allowCrossApp, Boolean allowBuildInPrecompile, Boolean throwIfNotFound, Boolean ensureIsUpToDate)
at System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.GetVPathBuildResultWithNoAssert(HttpContext 
context, VirtualPath virtualPath, Boolean noBuild, Boolean allowCrossApp, Boolean allowBuildInPrecompile, Boolean throwIfNotFound, Boolean ensureIsUpToDate)
at System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.GetVirtualPathObjectFactory(VirtualPath virtualPath, HttpContext context, Boolean allowCrossApp, Boolean throwIfNotFound)
at System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.CreateInstanceFromVirtualPath(VirtualPath virtualPath, Type requiredBaseType, HttpContext context, Boolean allowCrossApp)
at System.Web.UI.PageHandlerFactory.GetHandlerHelper(HttpContext context, String requestType, VirtualPath virtualPath, String physicalPath)
at System.Web.UI.PageHandlerFactory.GetHandler(HttpContext context, String requestType, String virtualPath, String path)
at 

Custom event details:
```

(Sorry for the margins but i dont know how to make them right.)

When i am looking at the logs there are no any other errors before this error.

The apps are using a MySQL server database each other.

The MySQL server works fine.

I tried all the info i found about this error but nothing yet.

Can you help me?

Comment: Runtime compilation of ASP.NET 4.x web apps can fail for quite a few causes. Try to precompile them and deploy again. At least that avoids runtime compilation.

Comment: This is a very generic error, there is no specific cause for this, so you can try to debug the cause using IIS [Debug Diagnostics Tool](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=58210), this tool will generate detail log file, which will help you to identify the problem.